# REST Why can't we have a character as query parameter

Tags: java, rest, jersey-1.0

`Tomcat 7.0` was failing to start for the following method definition

```
@GET
    @Path("/GetSeriesByIndex")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String getSeriesListByIndex(@QueryParam("indexCharacter")char indexCharacter){
        String allSeriesByIndex = null;
        ArrayList<SeriesListDTO> seriesListing=null;
        try{
            ProjectManager projectManager = new ProjectManager();
            seriesListing = projectManager.getSeriesListByIndex(indexCharacter);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            allSeriesByIndex = gson.toJson(seriesListing);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return allSeriesByIndex;
    }
```

with the error message

```
com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: Method, public java.lang.String tv.series.services.webService.TV_Services.getSeriesListByIndex(char), annotated with GET of resource, class tv.series.services.webService.TV_Services, is not recognized as valid Java method annotated with @HttpMethod.
```

On changing the type of `indexCharacter` to `String`, the system starts and everything works fine.

can somebody explain why this happens?

I am using `jersey 1.0.3` libraries. Maybe it was some bug in that release?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried it with `Character`?  Further to that, why would you want to limit your resource to only one character?

Comment: @Makoto: The service will ever require only one character, therefore I used a char. I understand why it was happening from znurgl answer. Thanks for your response. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is jersey's api docs: https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.7/jersey/javax/ws/rs/QueryParam.html

Converting a String to char? Why don't you use just String?

Comment: I did not know that all params are Strings. I thought they could be transmitted as chars. (First time REST). My method signature required a character only, So I defined the service method in the same way and not realizing the implications. 
Anyway..thanks for pointing this out for me.

Comment: Apart from the question if a char makes sense or using a String instead: ```must either be a primitive type``` from your linked documentation should be true for a char?